# Create a User-Defined Function to check if a car is available between two dates?

Tags: mysql, database, date, subquery, sql-function

I have a table called `Bookings` were a number of car reservations are stored with columns `CarNumber`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`. I need to create a User-Defined Function to check whether a car is available or not, if the car is available it should return a `1` and if not return a `0`.

The function so far:

`CREATE FUNCTION Available(StarDate DATE, EndDate DATE, CarNumber INT)
    RETURNS INTEGER NOT DETERMINISTIC
    RETURN`

I only just started to learn about user defined functions so could use some help.

`CREATE TABLE Bookings (CarNumber INT, StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE);`

`INSERT INTO Bookings (CarNumber, StartDate, EndDate)
    VALUES (6, '2018-01-02', '2018-01-15'),
            (1, '2018-01-03', '2018-01-05'),
            (3, '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04'),
            (8, '2018-01-04', '2018-01-30'),
            (10, '2018-01-10', '2018-01-13');`

Comment: ignoring the function at the moment can you add the code you would use to check car availability,

Comment: Make a SELECT that returns the wanted information and place that into the function where you replace the dates and id number with the variables

Comment: you do understand that we can't write such  a query without knowing the table structure and within some data

Comment: apparently we can :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `exists` subquery to check if the given date range overlaps any booking date range for the given car.

Consider the following syntax:

```
delimiter //

create function availability(
    pStartDate datetime, 
    pEndDate datetime, 
    pCarNumber int
)
returns bool deterministic
begin
    declare res bool;
    select not exists(
        select 1 
        from bookings 
        where startDate < pEndDate and endDate > pStartDate and carNumber = pCarNumber
    ) into res;
    return res;
end;
//
```